# New Laravel Install - Cant find Controllers

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-valet

I have a new Laravel project running Valet + (laravel 8.12).

Controller:

app->Http->Controllers->PageController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboard()
    {
        return view('show');
    }
}
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get(
    '/dashboard',
    [PageController::class, 'show']
)->name('dashboard');

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

I have a link on my homepage
href="dashboard"
however when this link is clicked I get an error:

```
lluminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [PageController] does not exist.
http://myportal.test/dashboard
```

I have tried running:
composer dump-autoload
php artisan route:cache
php artisan optimize
php artisan clear-compiled

I dont fully understand why when I added
php artisan ui vue --auth
why the routing had
[App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class
added for the route?

I have usually used:
route::get('/dashboard', 'PageController@show');
which usually works.

None of these have worked to solve the issue. I have another Laravel project running in the same Valet+ environment that is working fine (although using a different version of Laravel).

I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem online that has helped me solve this problem. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Add this on the top of your route `use App\Http\Controllers\PageController;`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Route::get(
    '/dashboard',
    [PageController::class, 'show']
)->name('dashboard');
```

to

```
Route::get(
    '/dashboard',
    [App\Http\Controllers\PageController::class, 'show']
)->name('dashboard');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply include the class, add the following at the top of the web.php file

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PageController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Include first your Controler in `web.php` useing
`use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;`
then create route just like this

`Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');`

full Code Try this one

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```